# Disable UISearchBar

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ios5, uisearchbar

I have a -as I hope- very simple question: how to disable an UISearchBar in IOS5 to avoid user interaction? I can't find setEnabled or something like this...

Thanks!

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Have you tried:

```
[searchBar setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];
```

?

Comment: Great answer, here's the Swift: `searchBar.userInteractionEnabled = false`

Answer (score 15):

In addition to setting user interaction, I also adjusted the alpha value as well, to make the appearance unique.

```
searchbar.alpha = .75;
```

Answer (score 6):

Try this

```
// Normal 
self.searchDisplayController.searchBar.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
self.searchDisplayController.searchBar.translucent = YES;
self.searchDisplayController.searchBar.searchBarStyle = UISearchBarStyleDefault;
self.searchDisplayController.searchBar.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

// Faded out
self.searchDisplayController.searchBar.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
self.searchDisplayController.searchBar.translucent = NO;
self.searchDisplayController.searchBar.searchBarStyle = UISearchBarStyleMinimal;
self.searchDisplayController.searchBar.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
```

Comment: I find `lightGrayColor` seems to be a bit extreme; something more around `[UIColor colorWithWhite:0.85 alpha:1]` looks right to me

Answer (score 3):

An extension for Swift 4 that provides functions to enable and disable the `UISearchBar`. Feel free to adjust the alpha value as you see fit, since color schemes in use can impact the result.

```
extension UISearchBar {
    func enable() {
        isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        alpha = 1.0
    }

    func disable() {
        isUserInteractionEnabled = false
        alpha = 0.5
    }
}
```

Then to disable the searchBar:

```
searchBar.disable()
```

To enable:

```
searchBar.enable()
```

Answer (score 0):

For Swift 3:

```
self.searchController.searchBar.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
```

Or if you want to still detect user interaction you can do this to disable the `UITextField` inside the `UISearchBar`:

```
(self.searchController.searchBar.value(forKey: "searchField") as! UITextField).isEnabled = false
```

Answer (score 0):

Really simply:

```
@IBOutlet weak var yourNameForSearchBar: UISearchBar!

viewDidLoad {
    yourNameForSearchBar.isHidden = true
}
```

this makes it so the SearchBar just hides and user-touches in its spot do nothing.  That way, when you want it shown, you just do the opposite (false).  You can also save the space, but that's outside the scope of this answer.